# how do we add buttons in human task and actions for it in jbpm?

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I am trying to develop a user registration process using jbpm workbench. following are the steps that i would like to do.

```
1.User will fill the details
2.The filled details are stored in separate db using the custom work item handler.
3.Email will generated to the user who filled the form with verification code.
4.User task – to confirm the verification code. - pending
5.If verification code is matched then message will be shown and the database table will be updated as it is verified. - pending
6.Then the registration process ends.
```

step 4 & 5 is pending. because step 4 need to be designed with form where that form should have verify button, when the user enters the verification code and click on theverify button should validate and responds immediately. 
So how to design the button in the form. i don't see any buoons in the form other than save, release, complete button while running the instances.

How do we design the human task with buttons?

Answer (score 0):

When using the form in the workbench, it will currently always show the complete button underneath.  But rather than using a confirm button, you could for example use a confirm checkbox that can be used in combination with the complete button.